# Retrieve PDF field "description text" with Itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

Is it possible to get the text shown in the red squares in my attached image? The image is showing part of a PDF document with several fields and their "title"

I don't know what they are called so im having a hard time searching for a solution :(

I can get all the field names and types. But when i debug i cant seem to find any option where the "caption", or whatever it is called, for a field is stored/accessed. If there is a link between the field and that text it would be lovely :)

If you don't know how to access that information with code, do you know what the text might be called so that i can try searching/debugging some more myself?

**Edit - added a bigger image, sorry for the NSA blackout of text, not sure i can share the customer PDF document...**
[image: example of PDF]

**Edit2 - added some PDFReader data about the document from VS quickWatch**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately **PDF does not know form field labels.** What you have most probably is regular page content located near some form fields (here I assume you have AcroForm form fields, not XFA form fields). And from the image alone it is not clear what kind of page content. If you shared the PDF form document, it might become easier to help.

Comment: Added a bigger image. The document contains several editable fields that have titles (in red). Those i want to find if possible

Comment: The text "may" be called annotations or labels but i cant seem to access those either...

Comment: As mentioned before, *from the image alone it is not clear what kind of page content. If you shared the PDF form document, it might become easier to help*.

Comment: As i wrote in the edit text. I cant share the customers document without permission, its pending... But i can try and give you some more info that the pdfreader gives me. Updating the post

Comment: Ok. So you have AcfoForm fields. AcfoForm fields definitively don't have labels. Thus, you have normal content. So you have to look whether you can apply text extraction or have to go for OCR.

Comment: Hello @merger, you say that you have a customer, which sounds as if you are using iTextSharp in a commercial context. In any case, you are using iTextSharp which means that either (1.) you are distributing the full source code you write for your customer under the AGPL license, or (2.) you are a customer of iText Software. If (1.), your "customer" probably isn't paying you. If he isn't paying you, you probably haven't got any obligations to help him. If (2.), you can share the document under an NDA with iText Software so that we can help you further.